# Automatic check if Vulkan is supported

Tags: drivers, vulkan, hardware-test

Is it possible for Ubuntu to check and give a clear message if my GPU is Vulkan-compatible?

I spent a lot of time troubleshooting why Vulkan doesn't work on my system:

```
$ vulkaninfo
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan API Version: 1.0.61

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/techtonik/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/techtonik/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Meta-layer VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation all 0 component layers appear to be valid.
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /usr/share//vulkan/icd.d/intel_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /usr/share//vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /usr/share//vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"

Instance Extensions:
====================
Instance Extensions count = 15
    VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2: extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2    : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
    VK_KHR_wayland_surface              : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface                  : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface                 : extension revision  6
    VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display         : extension revision  1
    VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  8
    VK_EXT_direct_mode_display          : extension revision  1
    VK_EXT_display_surface_counter      : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_display                      : extension revision 21
    VK_KHX_device_group_creation        : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities  : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities: extension revision  1
/build/vulkan-L06RNr/vulkan-1.0.61.1+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:1722: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

I've got NVIDIA GT 520 with latest driver installed, but many hours later it appeared that my GPU is just not in the list of supported technology https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver

I expected Ubuntu to warn me that there is no support for my GPU. Why it doesn't happen? Is it possible to do such check on a system level? If not, then can there be a protocol for vendors to at least provide lists of cards with explanation?

Comment: mine errors with VULKAN_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER so i think you're doing better than me

Comment: Make sure you have correctly installed the Vulkan library and drivers: sudo apt install libvulkan1 mesa-vulkan-drivers